# How to use svg image as background image in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, svg

I use svg in my react-native app next way:

```
import TestLogo from "../../assets/TestLogo.svg";
<TestLogo />
```

I use background image in next way:

```
import background from '../../assets/modules/auth/signUpPattern.png'
<ImageBackground source={background} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%',  alignItems: 'center'}}>
```

If I use the next syntax:

```
    import Background from '../../assets/modules/auth/signUpPattern.svg'
    <ImageBackground source={<Background />} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%',  alignItems: 'center'}}>
```

I got empty space, not svg image background, how to fix it?

Comment: Support of SVG images seems to be a feature of RN 0.61 (didn't test it, but read it [here](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/blog/2020/02/010/m4updates.html#svg-image-support)
If doesn't work, or you need support in RN < 0.61, you have to use an Component for this [like this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg)

Comment: I use react-native-svg and it works. The problem only how to use it background

Comment: You can't post your Background as Component to the source. At least you can try to use `data:` as uri-scheme (like described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image)) but I doubt that this will work. I've read something that svg doesn't work within `data:'. What's about to paste it as Children and use styling to scale-up it as you need. Have a look at [sourcecode of <ImageBackround> shows you, how it's implemented](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js#L65)

Comment: Does it work with 'data:', or you added it as Children? Nice that it helps you out.

Comment: @suther  'data:' doesnt work. I will try make as children

Comment: @befreeforlife hey, did you end up figuring it out?

Answer (score 12):

```
import TestLogo from "../../assets/TestLogo.svg";
<TestLogo />
```

You can use this for adding background Image for the screen. Just need to add the style to the TestLogo component.

> Example:

```
<TestLogo
   style={{
     position: 'absolute',
     top: 0,
     left: 0,
     right: 16,
     bottom: 0,
   }}
 />
```

Comment: I don't think you can directly import and use a SVG graphic unless using a library like react-native-svg like @Waleed Azhar says in his reply

Comment: Yes, If you are using typescript then you need to use third-party dependencies

Answer (score 1):

react-native doesn't support .svg formats. u can use library like [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg) 
or any other.

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside the container, style the parent, and that should do the work.

```
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import SVGShape from "../assets/icons/path";

export default ShapeSVG = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{
      position: "absolute",
      width: "100%",
      height: "32%",
      bottom: 0,
      zIndex: -1, 
}}>
      <SVGShape width={50} height={50} />
    </View>
  );
};
```